# Navigation, menu and look and feel disappears on Liferay 7 CE

Tags: liferay-7

I am trying to deploy and test a portlet on Liferay 7.0 CE version. All of a sudden I realized that the menu icon on top that displays the left navigation, the Add and the configure option on the top right and the menu on the top rightof each portlet that allows you to configure has all disappeared. I had seen and used it in the past, but am not aware at what point I lost all these options. Now I am unable to clear cache, add a new portlet or remove existing ones.

Can someone give me some ideas as to what could have happened? Could it be some javascript in my portlet that's conflicting with the bundle that holds these options? Or could something else be wrong?

Comment: *Could it be some javascript in my portlet* - How should we know without the code? *could something else be wrong?* Of course. A common cause for UI glitches is also unbalanced HTML generated by custom portlets, e.g. opening 2 `<div>`s and closing 3.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had got signed out which caused all the menu icons and navigation to disappear. I could only see the Sign-in link, but when I tried to Sign-in, sign-in did not work. The Sign-in pop-up stayed as it is. I could not see errors in any logs either. I had to undeploy the portlet after which the sign-in worked. Then I redeployed the portlet and its all good until I Sign-out and the icons disappear again and Sign-in does not work again.
Has anyone faced this issue? Why does the Sign-in not work with the portlet running? Do I need to change anything with the role?

My portlet.xml has :

```
   <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
```

My liferay-portlet.xml has :

```
<role-mapper>
    <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
</role-mapper>
<role-mapper>
    <role-name>guest</role-name>
    <role-link>Guest</role-link>
</role-mapper>
<role-mapper>
    <role-name>power-user</role-name>
    <role-link>Power User</role-link>
</role-mapper>
<role-mapper>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
    <role-link>User</role-link>
</role-mapper>
```